# Java scratch file unable to execute in intellij 2016

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-16

Previously i was using Intellij15 where the scratch file feature introduced and it was successfully execute java code there. But after upgrading to intellij16 i unable to execute scrach file of type java. 
Can someone tell me a way to work in intellij16

Comment: Did you tried the approach described in official documentation? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/scratches.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch **files** run fine for me on Intellij IDEA 2016.3

Steps followed:

1. Notice that there are Scratch **files** and Scratch **buffers** but only the former are runnable and is created via :

[image]

2. Then choose the language:

[image]

3. Add then create and execute the desired code, for example:

```java
class Blah{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Blah");
    }
}
```

See this in action below:

[image]